# How to return a generic Enum from a method that accepts a generic Enum?

Tags: java, generics, enums

I am trying to write a utility method that will accept an `enum` of any type and return an `enum` of the **same** type, but with a different value.

Suppose I have the following two `enum`:

```
enum Pet {
    DOG("Puppy"),
    CAT("Jazmine"),
    LIZARD("Spock");

    private final String value;

    Pet(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}

enum Topping {
    PEPPERONI("Meat Saucers"),
    ONION("Like Ogres"),
    ANCHOVIES("Spicy Fish");

    private final String value;

    Topping(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

In my application, a user needs the ability to "edit" an `enum` value. For example, when the user wants to edit their `Pet`, they are presented with a list of the `enum` values and can select a new one from that list.

What I'm trying to do is write one method that can handle any number of different types of `enum` (ie: both `Pet` and `Topping`).

Since I am not very familiar with generics yet, here is a very poorly "coded" example of what I'm trying to do:

```
public static GenericEnumType changeValue(Enum<?> e) {
        
    // Present user with list of e.values(), user can select new value
    String newValue = getUserInput();
    return GenericEnumType.valueOf(newValue);
}
```

Is there a way to accomplish such a thing?
From my research, I've found that it may be difficult to retrieve values from generic `enum` because the `values()` method is not actually available at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static Enum<?> changeValue(Enum<?> e) {
    String newValue = getUserInput();
    return Enum.valueOf(e.getClass(), newValue);
}
```

`Enum.valueOf` could throws **IllegalArgumentException** and **NullPointerException**. You should handle it

Comment: Yes, exceptions must be handled, for sure. About your solution, the one thing I think is strange is how the method takes an enum value (i.e. Enum<?> e) in order to retrieve the class object from the enum. I think it's better to simply take the class literal directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
    enum MyEnum1 { VALUE1, VALUE2 }
    enum MyEnum2 { VALUE3, VALUE4 }

    public static <E extends Enum<E>> E valueOf(
            Class<E> enumClass, String value) {
        return Enum.valueOf(enumClass, value);
    }
```

Then

```
System.out.println(valueOf(MyEnum1.class, "VALUE1"));
```

This is generally what you can do when you need a method that accepts any types of enum. In this particular case, since you are parsing only, might as well simply use:

```
Enum.valueOf(MyEnum1.class, "VALUE1")
```

Comment: However, this method does not provide users with a list of available values for the given enum. I suppose I would need to also pass in a list of values as a parameter?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are facing with difficulty to find the enums from given enum. Then you can use reflection to find them. Following you can find what I did.

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
    import java.lang.reflect.Method;
    import java.util.Arrays;

    public class Test {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException, IOException {
            System.out.println(changeValue(Pet.DOG));

        }
        public static Enum changeValue(Enum<?> e) throws NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException, IOException {

            // Present user with list of e.values(), user can select new value
            Method method = e.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("values");
            Object obj = method.invoke(null);
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString((Object[]) obj));

            String newValue = getUserInput();
            return e.valueOf(e.getClass(),newValue);
        }

        private static String getUserInput() throws IOException {
            System.out.println("select one of the enum from list and enter the name");
            BufferedReader reader =
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            String name = reader.readLine();
            return name;
        }
    }
    enum Pet {
        DOG("Puppy"),
        CAT("Jazmine"),
        LIZARD("Spock");

        private final String value;

        Pet(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public String getValue() {
            return value;
        }
    }
    enum Topping {
        PEPPERONI("Meat Saucers"),
        ONION("Like Ogres"),
        ANCHOVIES("Spicy Fish");

        private final String value;

        Topping(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public String getValue() {
            return value;
        }
    }
```